# SQL Server BCP works with table, but specify specific columns and it fails, why

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the EXAMPLE below, it works creating a file with all rows and columns in FTP_export_BAC table. But if I specify specific columns only to be exported, i.e. SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Asce.... it fails. Any ideas?

```
DECLARE @Command varchar(512)

set @Command = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM myDatabase.dbo.[FTP_export_BAC]" queryout "C:\bcp\bcptest.txt" -T -c -S' + @@SERVERNAME

print @Command  
EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Yikes it was something silly, the string has to be on one line when specifying column names